# Outlook: Creating a hotkey to open a search folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, hotkeys

I'm using Outlook Professional Plus 2010. I've created a search folder called "Ram's Inbox", but I need a quick way to open it with the keyboard. So far my best way is to type ctrl-y and then search for my folder and press enter. I'd be happy to have a direct hotkey that'll put me on the folder in one press. Is it possible to create one? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way I can think of is the one I use on one of my work computers.

Create a Shortcut on your desktop point it to your Outlook.

Mine is as stated.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE
```

Then you insert the switch. Using **Ram's Inbox** as an example.

**/select "outlook:Ram's Inbox"**

Here is what yours will look like.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE" /select "outlook:Ram's Inbox"
```

*Note: Be sure to use Quotations around separated words like in my example and your Example.*

Now just **Name** it and **save**.

Now **Right Click** it and hit **Properties**.

Here is the example of mine.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE" /select "outlook:Corporate Comm"
```

Notice the Shortcut key set it what you like.

Now all you have to do is push the key and it will open up the folder.

[image]

If you want the shortcut to open in the existing window type this at the end.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE" /select "outlook:Corporate Comm"` **/recycle**

Comment: Hmm, my Outlook exe is in a different way, so I tried this in Windows' Run dialog: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" /select "outlook:Ram's Inbox"` but Outlook gave an error dialog saying "Cannot display the selected folder or item". Any idea what to do?

Comment: Is `Ram's Inbox` your search folder? is it in a sub folder??

Comment: Example `/select "outlook:Inbox/Ram's Inbox"`

Comment: It's a search folder. I don't know whether it's considered a subfolder, it's inside "Search Folders" which is inside "Ram.Rachum@whatever.com". I tried your new example, didn't work.

Comment: `/select "outlook:Search Folders/Ram's Inbox"`should work then.

Comment: Good news and bad news. The good news is that it worked. The bad news is that it started a new instance of Outlook, while I'd like to open the folder in the existing instance.

Comment: Gotcha let me see if I can play around with it. I will get back to you in a little while about to eat my 4:00am lunch.

Comment: added it to the end of the answer check it out. `/recycle`